# iOS bluetooth not discovering devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'm testing an app to display nearby bluetooth devices. For now, the code is simple as following:

```
- (IBAction)scanForDevices:(id)sender
{
    UIButton * btn = sender;
    if(self.cManager.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth is %s",[self centralManagerStateToString:self.cManager.state]);
    }

    if(!self.isSearching){
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
        [self.cManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
        btn.titleLabel.text = @"Stop";
        self.isSearching = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        btn.titleLabel.text = @"Search";
        self.isSearching = NO;
    }
}

#pragma mark - CBCentral Delegate
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    NSLog(@"Ready to discovery..");
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"Receive periferal: %@", peripheral);
}
```

But every time I pressed button to execute scanForDevices, callback function got called but with null value for peripheral. I'm not sure my device is working correctly. On my laptop, both my iphone 4S (6.0.1) and ipad (7.1) were discovered but not from iphone nor ipad.

Comment: You have to start somewhere. Question #1 is 'can the devices I'm trying to discover be discovered?' Try using https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110?mt=8 and tell us if you can actually see the devices.

Comment: Apparently its not discovering expected devices. What do you mean by 'can the devices i'm trying to discover be discovered?' if my macbook can discover my iphone and ipad, why not the other way or each other?

Comment: So my understanding is that you're trying to discover your macbook from your iDevices? Correct? Well your macbook is only discoverable when you have the Bluetooth settings open (System Preferences -> Bluetooth). If you take a close look at they Bluetooth settings windows it will say 'Now discoverable as "your macbook's name"'. Otherwise, your macbook won't be discoverable by your iDevices.

Comment: I already tested it while bluetooth setting was opening. iphone did not discover macbook nor ipad

Comment: Have you been able to fix your issue?

Comment: no, apparently my friends iphone 4s also cannot detect any bluetooth device. Funny thing is android phone detect my iphone and can request pairing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reseting the network settings on the devices?  This has fixed some of the random corebluetooth related issues I've had.